# Integrate $\int\frac{1}{x^2-3}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate $\int\frac{1}{x^2-3}dx$

I'm trying to come into a form in order to apply this formula :

$\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}dx=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\ln|\frac{x-1}{x+1}|+C$

Need a bit help on this problem.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: sub $x=\sqrt{3}t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward way to proceed is to note that $$\frac{1}{x^2-3}=\frac{1}{\left(x+\sqrt3\right)\left(x-\sqrt3\right)}.$$ Next, find constants $A$ and $B$ such that $$\frac{1}{x^2-3}=\frac{A}{x+\sqrt3}+\frac{B}{x-\sqrt3}.$$ At that point, the individual antiderivatives should be clear, and you'll be able to condense into a single antiderivative using logarithm rules.

However, if you're bound and determined to use that formula, note that $$x^2-3=3\left(\frac{x^3}3-1\right)=3\left(\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt3}\right)^2-1\right),$$ so letting $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt3},$ we have $x=u\sqrt 3$ as a fine substitution to make.

Comment: @Cameroon don't know why im getting as a result
 $\frac{\ln|x-\sqrt{3}|-\ln|x+\sqrt{3}|}{2\cdot3}$ instead of $\frac{\ln|x-\sqrt{3}|-\ln|x+\sqrt{3}|}{2\cdot\sqrt{3}}$ (online calc)


$$\int\frac{dx}{3\left(\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt3}\right)^2-1\right)}dx=\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{dx}{\left(\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt3}\right)^2-1\right)}dx=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\ln|\frac{x-\sqrt{3}}{x+\sqrt{3}}|dx=\frac{ln|x-\sqrt{3}|-|x+\sqrt{3}|}{2\cdot3}$$

Comment: @John: It's because you didn't quite follow through with the substitution. Since $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt 3},$ then $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac1{\sqrt 3}.$ Thus, $$\int\frac1{x^2-3}\,dx=\frac1{\sqrt 3}\int\frac1{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt 3}\right)^2-1}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt 3}\,dx,$$ or $$\int\frac1{x^2-3}\,dx=\frac1{\sqrt 3}\int\frac1{u^2-1}\,du.$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: $\int\frac{1}{x^2-3}dx=\int\frac{1}{3\cdot((\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}})^2-1)}dx=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\int\frac{1}{(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}})^2-1}dx\:\:$ now sub. $\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}=t\:\:$ from here $dx=\sqrt{3}dt$ 

than $\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{1}{t^2-1}\cdot\sqrt{3}dt=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\cdot\int\frac{1}{t^2-1}dt$

than applied integration formula:

$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\ln\frac{|t-1|}{|t+1|}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}\cdot\ln\frac{|x-2-\sqrt{3}|}{|x-2-\sqrt{3}|}$ blind to my mistakes :(

Comment: @John: You've made a mistake in your last step. $$\frac{|t-1|}{|t+1|}=\cfrac{\left|\frac{x}{\sqrt 3}-1\right|}{\left|\frac{x}{\sqrt 3}+1\right|},$$ so $$\int\frac1{x^2-3}\,dx=\frac1{2\sqrt 3}\ln\cfrac{\left|\frac{x-\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3}\right|}{\left|\frac{x+\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3}\right|}+C,$$ or $$\int\frac1{x^2-3}\,dx=\frac1{2\sqrt 3}\ln\cfrac{\left|x-\sqrt 3\right|}{\left|x+\sqrt 3\right|}+C.$$ Does that make sense?

Comment: Cameron yes I noticed my mistake, thank you and sorry for bothering  :)

Comment: No problem! I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply and divide by 2√3 , then write 2√3 in the form of (x+√3)-(x-√3) , and split the denominator into (x+√3)(x-√3) , split the terms and now it's quite straightforward.